# jQuery Masonry does not work in IE but works fine in chrome and mozilla

Tags: jquery

Maybe jQuery Masonry does not work in IE6-9. Any DIV or tags does not showed in pages. Pages works fine in at least latest Chrome and Mozilla browsers.

IE browser says:
"Error: DIV with ID "wrapper" not found on page."

even that is founding there!

You can see my pages:
http://www.downrigger.pages.fi/

Any ideas?

Comment: You are implementing Masonry in the most peculiar way; it's a layout plugin that works on a group of identically classed divs within a #container. What are you actually trying to do with it - meaning, what shall Masonry do for visitors of your website? BTW, Masonry works well in IE8 also...

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a problem getting jQuery to work in IE (even though it maybe slower in older versions).

From the errors I'm getting in Firefox, your page shouldn't work in any browser.

I can see from the link you provided is that the path to your jQuery Masonry plugin is not getting found:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OK, thank you. Ia added line: <script src="http://kuvat.uuu.fi/99_jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>

Comment: Ok now I'm getting another error: "TypeError:$ is not a function". Meaning your jQuery library is not getting referenced. To ensure that nothing is interrupting your jQuery library, move "<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="http://kuvat.uuu.fi/99_jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>" so its above the code where you start calling masonry.

Comment: Thanks, it ALMOST is working now with IE, but location of the DIVs is not correct.